# How to concatenate list values in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

If I have a function

```
let rec function n = 
   if n<0 then [] 
   else n-2 @ function n-2 ;;
```

I get an error saying that the expression `function n-2` is a list of int but it is expecting an int.

How do I concatenate the values to return all the n-2 values above zero as a list?

I cannot use the `List` module to fold. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title asks how to concatenate lists, but your question seems rather different.

To concatenate lists, you can use the `@` operator. In many cases, code that depends on this operator is slower than it needs to be (something to keep in mind for later :-).

Here are some things I see wrong with the code you give:

a. You can't name a function `function`, because `function` is a keyword in OCaml.

b. If you use the `@` operator, you should have lists on both sides of it. As near as I can see, the thing on the left in your code is not a list.

c. Function calls have higher precedence than infix operators. So `myfun n - 2` is parsed as `(myfun n) - 2`. You probably want something closer to `myfun (n - 2)`.

Even with these changes, your code seems to generate a list of integers that are 2 apart, which isn't what you say you want. However, I can't understand what the function is actually supposed to return.

Comment: I realize the problem is oddly worded. I was trying to create a generic problem which exemplified the problem I was experiencing using a simple problem and thats what I came up with.
a) I used `function` in this example as a generic name
b) & c) were my problems (mainly c)). Thanks!

Comment: i think you've seen that your attempt to clarify the problem paired with your inexperience with the language bit you pretty hard here. Glad you got it worked out though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not concatenating lists, but concatenating ints instead. This is done by the :: operator. So your code would look like:

```
     else (n-2)::(fun (n-2))
```

Although I could see this function possibly not producing the desired output if you put in negative numbers. For example if you pass through n = 1, n-2 will evaluate to -1 which is less than zero.